# how to open an Offline pdf in ionic 2 application in adobe reader

Tags: pdf, ionic2, offline, documentviewer

Trying the below code to open an offline pdf in ionic 2 application but the code is opening a pdf file in cleverdox viewer instead of adobe reader, how could i set adobe reader by default here to make pdf functional. Thanks in Advance.

```js
open()
  {
  const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My PDF'
  }
  this.document.viewDocument('file:///android_asset/www/assets/test.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
}
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

No idea if you got this resolved but here's what fixed the issue for me:

Make sure you are using the latest version of the document Viewer plugin.

```
open() {
  const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
    title: 'My PDF',
    openWith: { enabled: true }, //this will allow you to open the document with an external application
    // any more options
  };
  this.document.viewDocument('file:///android_asset/www/assets/test.pdf', 'application/pdf', options);
}
```

The problem with @rj7 's code is that he added a function into what should be a nested object. For more information on the options you can pull through into this function, see the following URL: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Hope that helps to anyone stuck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try openWith() like below,

```
open()
  {
  const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My PDF',
  openWith() {
    enabled: true
   }
  }
  this.document.viewDocument('file:///android_asset/www/assets/test.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
}
```

Comment: error: Type '{ title: string; openWith(): void; }' is not assignable to type 'DocumentViewerOptions'. Types of property 'openWith' are incompatible. Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '{ enabled: boolean; }'. Property 'enabled' is missing in type '() => void'.